# Input validation phone number

Tags: java, regex, user-input, validation

I am trying to find a way to make field constraints for input of a phone number.
Example:
`France (country code 33) local number 0142687984` should be input as
`33142687984`

and not for example
`00331 42687984, 0033 (1) 42687984, +33 1 42 68 79 84`  etc

basically the number should never start with 0, should not include spaces or signs like + ( ) etc and should have at least 9 digits

I have been trying to find a sample for deluge scripting but no success. Please help

I have this so far :

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String nom = request.getParameter("nom");
    String prenom = request.getParameter("prenom");
    String phone = request.getParameter("phone");
    String adressefacturation = request.getParameter("adressefacturation");
    String ZIPfacturation = request.getParameter("ZIPfacturation");
    String paysfacturation = request.getParameter("paysfacturation");
    String adresseexpedition = request.getParameter("adresseexpedition");
    String ZIPexpedition = request.getParameter("ZIPexpedition");

    String paysexpedition = request.getParameter("paysexpedition");
    String CardNumber = request.getParameter("CardNumber");
    String CardDateOfExpiry = request.getParameter("CardDateOfExpiry");

    String password = request.getParameter("password");         
}
```

Comment: Do you want to add the validation directly to your bean property, or where should the check be performed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compute some posibilities you have to split the entered string (after test of ".. (1) .."):

```
    // String[] litteralPhone = request.getParameter("phone").split(" ") ;
    final String litteralPhone = "0033 (119999999990";
    final int i = litteralPhone.indexOf(")");
    if (i > 0) {
        if (litteralPhone.substring(i).length() > 8) {
            System.out.println(litteralPhone.replaceAll(
                "^[0]{1,}|[ ]{0,}\\(|\\)[ ]{0,}", ""));
        } else {
            System.out.println("error with ()");
        }
    } else {
        // suppress trailing ( 
        final String[] tabNum = litteralPhone.replaceAll("\\(|\\)", "").split(" ");

        switch (tabNum.length) {
            case 1 : // 003311236549879879
               tabNum[0] = tabNum[0].replaceAll("^[0]{1,}", "");
               if (tabNum[0].length() < 10) { // tune this lenght
                      System.out.println("error 1");
                }
                break;
            case 2 : // 033 01234567890
                tabNum[0] = tabNum[0].replaceAll("^[0]{1,}", "");
                tabNum[1] = tabNum[1].replaceAll("^[0]", "");
                if (tabNum[1].length() < 8) {
                    System.out.println("error 2");
                }
                break;
            case 3 : // +33 1 012346577979
                tabNum[0] = tabNum[0].replaceAll("^[0]{1,}", "");
                tabNum[2] = tabNum[2].replaceAll("^[0]", "");
                if (tabNum[2].length() < 8) {
                    System.out.println("error 3");
                }
                // add all cases here
            default :
                System.out.println("not a good phone number");
                break;
        }
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (final String string : tabNum) {
            sb.append(string);
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

"basically the number should never start with 0, should not include spaces or signs like + ( ) etc and should have at least 9 digits" so I assume you accept only number that starts with 1-9 digit and then can only contain other digits (at least 8 of them).

It thats what you want try this regex `[1-9][0-9]{8,}`

```
System.out.println("123456789".matches("[1-9][0-9]{8,}"));//true
System.out.println("12345678".matches("[1-9][0-9]{8,}"));//false
System.out.println("012345678".matches("[1-9][0-9]{8,}"));//false
```

Comment: You'are missing the requirement of the leading 33 which is amendable

Comment: I assume France (33) was only example, not requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to match  `/^33\d{9}$/`

Comment: This only accepts numbers of exactly length 11 starting with 33.